# Resolve row versioning with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ormlite-servicestack

I am trying to model a new database. One of the requirements is to keep versions of different rows. Here a sample of 2 versions of the same object:

```
ID | UID                                  | Name  | Date
--------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | 734FD814-024D-4795-AFD0-34FECF89A13A | Alpha | 2013-02-08
 2 | 734FD814-024D-4795-AFD0-34FECF89A13A | Bravo | 2013-02-09
```

In order to have a foreign key with this table as a reference I need to specify a primary key. The two candidates are `ID` and `UID` with the first as an `auto increment` number and the second as a manually generated unique identifier per object.

**Limitation :**

When selecting `ID` as primary key:

- When a new version of the object is created, all references to an older version became invalid and must be updated
- Manually updating all references on each insert is not an option, very heavy

When selecting `UID` as primary key:

- `UID` is not unique and therefore cannot use it alone, must be associated with an other field and used within a complex primary key
- All other fields that would be used may change as well an brake the foreign key references.

Any suggestions about what would be the best approach (lightest as possible) to overcome these limitations?

**PS :** I am using OrmLite to model the database using POCO objects.

Comment: What is the reason for keeping multiple versions? For keeping references to particular versions, or purely for keeping track of historical changes?

Comment: do you have to keep versions in the same table ? or can you store it in some kind historical table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common scenario in financial applications.  An excellent approach is to mark one row as active.  For example:

```
ObjectID, StartDt, EndDt, ...other columns...
```

where `[StartDt, EndDt>` marks the time interval where the row was the "actual" row.  You can join like:

```
join    YourTable yt
on      yt.ObjectId  = otherTable.ObjectID
        and yt.StartDt is not null
        and yt.EndDt is null -- Select active row
```

Answer (score 0):

The fields that don't change version to version (which could just be the ID) could be put into another table.  That's the table to which you link.  The version-specific information is then in another table.  To help with joining to the latest version info you could have a IsLatest flag that you keep current in that table.